# Angular 4 Reactive Form cannot read property invalid of undefined

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I am using a reactive form defined in my component as such:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.client = this.params.get('client')

  this.profile_form = this.fb.group({
    id: [this.client.id],
    name: [this.client.name, [Validators.required]],
    address: [this.client.address],
    target_weight: [this.client.target_weight, [Validators.required]],
    target_weight2: [this.client.target_weight2, [Validators.required]],
    referred_by: [this.client.referred_by]
  })

}
```

and in my template I have:

```
<div class="row" padding-left>
  <div class="col" no-padding>
    <ion-item class="better-validation" [class.invalid]="target_weight.invalid && profile_form.dirty">
      <ion-label floating>Target Weight (High)</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="target_weight"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div padding-left *ngIf="target_weight.invalid && profile_form.dirty" class=" text-danger">
      High target weight is required
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" no-padding padding-right>

    <!-- Line causing the error -->
    <ion-item class="better-validation" [class.invalid]="target_weight2.invalid && profile_form.dirty">
      <ion-label floating>Target Weight (Low) {{ target}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" formControlName="target_weight2"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

If something is wrong I don't understand why the validation for `target_weight` isn't also throwing an error.  Both `this.client.target_weight` and `this.client.target_weight2` are `null`.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Comment: What's the value of this.params?

Comment: there is a ton of information in params.  I'm really only confused why 1 field out of the all others (there are others that I did not include for brevity) is causing the error

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the form first with its default value and then patch your object values.

```
this.profile_form = this.fb.group({
id: [0],
name: ['', [Validators.required]],
address: [''],
target_weight: ['', [Validators.required]],
target_weight2: ['', [Validators.required]],
referred_by: ['']});

this.profile_form.patchValue(this.client);
```

Comment: that would not explain why only 1 field is causing errors